# Show that the set $P_3=\{x=\frac{k}{3^n}\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that all I need to show is that $P_3$ is nonempty, closed under subtraction, and closed under multiplication, but I'm not sure how I should choose my elements. I feel like I *should* choose $a,b \in P_3$ such that $a=\frac{k}{3^n}$ and $b=\frac{j}{3^m}$ where $k,j,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, but I run into problems when trying to show that it is closed under subtraction. Can I just let $a=\frac{k}{3^n}$ and $b=\frac{j}{3^n}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that $m=n$ as follows. If $m$ and $n$ are different, with $m>n$, multiply $k/3^n$ by

$$\frac{3^{m-n}}{3^{m-n}}$$

and you get the same number.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot; your first inclination is correct, since you must choose arbitrary elements of $P_3$. You may, however, assume that $n\ge m$, so that

$$a-b=\frac{k}{3^n}-\frac{j}{3^m}=\frac{a-j3^{n-m}}{3^n}\;;$$

clearly the greatest common divisor of $a-j3^{n-m}$ and $3^n$ must be a power of $3$, so $a-b\in P_3$. For $b-a$ you may either use essentially the same argument or simply observe that $x\in P_3$ iff $-x\in P_3$.

Answer (score 1):

We can restrict to the elements of the form $\frac{k}{3^n}$ with $n \geq 0$, for if we have $n < 0$, we can replace the pair $k,n$ by $k\cdot 3^{-n}, 0$, resulting in the same value $\frac{k\cdot 3^{-n}}{1} = \frac{k}{3^n}$.

For $a = \frac{k}{3^n}$ and $b = \frac{l}{3^m}$ with $n,m \geq 0$, you have: $$ a - b = \frac{3^mk - 3^n l}{3^{n+m}},$$ which is of the sought form.

Comment: I got this the first time I worked the problem, but what if $m$ or $n$ is a negative number? Then we the numerator won't always be an integer.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops If $m$ is negative you could easily replace $a$ by an equivalent fraction with $m=0$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Thanks, I just added it to the answer as you were writing.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops: Is it OK now?

Comment: @Feanor Nicely caught! (on both your part and TheMobiusLoops')

Comment: I think so. Thank you.